# converter wave 24 bit to 16 bit

Tags: python, signals, wave, pyaudio

i wish to convert some wavs that are 
48kHz 24 bit file.wav   to 48kHz  16 bit  file-2.wav

```
import wave 
origAudio = wave.open("Sample_5073.wav","r")
frameRate = origAudio.getframerate()
nChannels = origAudio.getnchannels()
sampWidth = origAudio.getsampwidth()
nbframe=origAudio.getnframes()
da = np.fromstring(origAudio.readframes(48000), dtype=np.int16)
left, right = da[0::2], da[1::2]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If converting files from 24 to 16 bit is the only thing you want to do, you could use [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/), it doesn't get much easier than that:

```
sox file.wav -b 16 file-2.wav
```

SoX can also do many more things, just have a look at its [man page](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html).

If you want to use Python, I recommend the [soundfile](http://pysoundfile.readthedocs.io/) module:

```
import soundfile as sf

data, samplerate = sf.read('file.wav')
sf.write('file-2.wav', data, samplerate, subtype='PCM_16')
```

Specifying `subtype='PCM_16'` isn't even strictly necessary, since it's the default anyway.

If you really want to do it with the built-in `ẁave` module, have a look at my [tutorial about the `wave` module](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/mgeier/python-audio/blob/master/audio-files/audio-files-with-wave.ipynb).